# How do I make a SIP call from behind an HTTP Proxy?

Tags: proxy, voip, sip

We browse websites using an HTTP proxy; there's no direct internet access. The only VoIP program that works out-of-the-box in our network is Skype and it's using that proxy too.
For example, I want to talk to someone who's using Linphone. Is it possible? Maybe through some web site.

Comment: Do you want to call someone using Linphone or do you realy want to call someone who is using Linphone?

Comment: the latter. I wrote exactly the same: "who's using Linphone"

Comment: Well, I'm assuming the person using Linphone is registered to a SIP provider therefore has a landline number for you to call. Can't you use Skype credits to call that number? HOw does that relate to the fact you are behind that HTTP proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To date, there's no good SIP implementation that supports TCP, so I stuck with UDP. Even if there was, others still use UDP

We have a functional socks5 proxy with UDP bind, but there's no SIP software that supports it.

On Linux it is theoretically possible to use `Dante` proxifier.

It is also possible to write my own SIP proxy with socks5 UDP bind support and run it in our LAN.

Comment: This is not answer. However, Linphone *does* support TCP, and it actually depends on the SIP provider. Try Linphone's own SIP service: http://www.linphone.org/free-sip-service.html . If configured correctly, it supports both UDP and TLS (and most probably TCP).

Comment: > Linphone does support TCP

Comment: Only for SIP itself, but not for RTP

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linphone [from inside web browsers](http://www.linphone.org/about.html):

> on web browsers in 2013 (Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft Internet Explorer, Apple Safari)

To install it under Firefox you need to go to [LinphoneWeb](http://web.linphone.org/) and allow Firefox to automatically install the extension. Since this Linphone browser plug-in operates from within the web browser, I expect that it will respect any proxy settings that the browser itself honors.

Linphone supports TCP, but it actually depends on the SIP provider. Try [Linphone's own SIP service](http://www.linphone.org/free-sip-service.html). If Linphone is configured correctly, it supports both UDP and TLS (and most probably TCP).

See also:

- [Easy voice talk between 2 computers in 2 countries?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150565/easy-voice-talk-between-2-computers-in-2-countries/151456#151456)

Comment: looks like their plugin suffers same limitations as desktop Linphone.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Both SIP registration and voice data don't go through http.

Comment: Please edit your original question to include exactly what you did (which browser, which SIP provider, etc.) and exactly what didn't work. Otherwise no one around here can help you.